# Elasticsearch 'size:' vs MongoDB batch_size

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

For my thesis I'm currently investigating the speed (down to milliseconds) of Elasticsearch and MongoDB.

I've noticed that, compared to MongoDB, Elasticsearch is very consistent when it comes to the speed at which it returns data and the total items found. Where other MongoDB takes a longer time to return data the more results are found, Elasticsearch's response time is almost always the same, regardless of the total amount of requests sent.

My hypothesis is that in Elasticsearch, when using the size operator, the number of documents that are actually looked up and retrieved after the search in the indexes is finished is exactly the amount set in the size operator. Where in MongoDB this is not the case, in MongoDB all documents that matched in the index are retrieved, and only the top X amount is eventually returned to the client based on the cursor's batch_size and eventually the max limit() that is set.

I have no way, other than to spend hours looking through the source code, to figure out if this hypothesis is correct, or if something else is going on that I must have missed.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, any responses are appreciated and will help me further my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a bit clearer how Elasticsearch actually retrieves results: It uses [query then fetch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#query-then-fetch).

So if you search for N results, the first phase will **query** all the shards involved and return a list of their N results containing the score and the ID — not other information. In the second phase you **fetch** the top N global results by their ID. So you will retrieve more scores and IDs than you need, but you will only fetch the actual results.